# Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in

Tags: php, undefined, offset, explode

I get such an error when I want to draw data with curl.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/data.php on line 52

Code is :

```
function draw($one,$two,$number,$resource) {
    $draw= explode($one,$resource);
    $draw= explode($two,$draw[$number]);
    $draw= $draw[0];
    return $draw;   
}
```

Php code :

```
$resource2 = curl_exec($ch);
$date = draw('name="popupCal_input" type="text" value="','"',1,$resource2 );
$formid = draw('<form id="','" name="',3,$resource2 );
$validate = draw('<input type="text" name="','" value="',1,$resource2 );
$validateval = draw('id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="','" autocomplete="off"',4,$resource2 );
$submit = draw('<input type="submit" name="','" value="',1,$resource2 );
```

Same code is running on another server. But on my server doesn't work. Do I need to add a module to the server for this function?

Comment: How do you think we can guess what is inside your variables? Magic? Please update your question with missing information.

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example call with an explanation of the error. Hopefully it helps you now. If it does not and you still get the same error please provide an example string with which the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code splits the string `$resource` with the separator `$one` and then takes the part at index `$number` of that and splits it based on the separator `$two`, from which it then returns the first part.

The problem you encounter is, that there are not `$number` parts when splitting the `$resource` with `$one`. You can insert the following line to catch that:

```
//...
$draw = explode($one,$resource);
if (count($draw) <= $number) {
    return '';
}
$draw= explode($two,$draw[$number]);
//...
```

The code you have will now work as shown below.

```
$input = 
    '<div>
        <input type="text" name="terminator" value="I\'ll be back">
        <input type="text" name="snakesonaplane" value="Enough is enough. I have had it with these motherf***ing snakes on this motherfu***ing plane.">
    </div>';
$output = draw('<input type="text" name="', '" value="', 1, $input);
//$output = 'terminator" ';
```

Now in case for the same input the function would be called with the parameters `draw('<input type="text" name="', '" value="', 3, $input)` you would get the error you currently get. With the fix you will get no error, but `$output` will be an empty string (`''`) instead. (Which is OK, because there is no third input in the string.